# How to add even on ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android

Here is my program, but if I click nav_exit, my program is exiting. It isn't working as it should when I click. Help me please.

> 1.navigation_menu.xml

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_exit"

        android:title="EXIT" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"

        android:title="gallery" />

</group>

<item android:title="ssssssss">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"

            android:title="share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_se2nd"

            android:title="se2nd" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"

            android:title="send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

> 2.MainActivity  is not working on click menu.

```
package info.mt_online.www.myapplicationv1;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
           int id = item.getItemId();
           if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
               finish();
               System.exit(0);
               return true;
           }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It is not working. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: what you want actually? Question title and description are totally different. Update your question as per your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to `exit` app using `NavigationView` menu `Item`. To do this, you have to implement `NavigationItemSelectedListener` and in method `onNavigationItemSelected()` check your desired `nav_exit` and `exit` from the application by calling `finish()`.

Add below code in your `MainActivity` inside `onCrate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...........
    .................

    // NavigationView
    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
               finish();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

**FYI,** `onOptionsItemSelected()` is used for handling `Toolbar` option `MenuItems` click events.